# Integer Range in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm a newbie to Ruby, I have a problem following the Poignant Guide to Ruby:

Does this expression return true?

2005..2009 === 2007

But I don't know why I got this warning message from the following code

```
wishTraditional.rb:4: warning: integer literal in conditional range
```

code:

```
def makTimeLine(year)
if 1984 === year
        "Born."
elsif 2005..2009 === year
        "Sias."
else
        "Sleeping"
end
end
puts makTimeLine(2007)
```

and the it return Sleeping, which is wrong and should be the Sias

BTW what does the two dots mean? How can I find more information about it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you better use something like that :

```
elsif (2005..2009).include?(year)
```

Here is the documentation about [Ruby ranges](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Range.html#M000691)

Update: if you insist on using ===, you should enclose the range in parentheses:

```
elseif (2005..2009) === year
```

Comment: Thanks Baramin, I just figure it out by myself, this is covered in the previous chapter which I skipped. I wouldn't skip chapter again!

Comment: It is because of operator precedence: `===` binds before `...`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14258487/1400991

Answer (score 3):

For independent expressions, yes, you'll need to put range literals in parentheses.
But your if/elsif chain would be cleaner as a case statement, which uses === for comparison:

```
def makTimeLine(year)
  case year
  when 1984
    "Born."
  when 2005..2009
    "Sias."
  else
    "Sleeping"
  end
end
```