# How does Ruby's range and triple equals (===) work?

Tags: ruby, boolean

I'm reading Why's guide, and trying some of the commands in the ruby terminal side-by-side. One thing doesn't match up. I'm running Ruby 1.9.3.

In the book it says a valid command is:

```
if 1890..1913 === 1895
   echo "works"
end
```

However, when I do this, it just gives me

```
warning: (irb):27: warning: integer literal in conditional range
=> nil
```

Some more fascinating experiments

```
1895..1913 === 1895
> ArgumentError: bad value for range
from (irb):31
from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'

x = 1895..1913
x === 1895
> true
```

This is interesting because (coming from python) I would have thought the last two executions were identical, however, it seems not so. I wonder if anyone could reveal more insight into why all those experiments failed, and how the === works.

Comment: If you are using a non-standard method such as `echo`, you should explain what it does. Otherwise, if it is irrelevant to the question, you should clean up your example code to make it more reader friendly.

Comment: @sawa Sorry, was doing some bash. It's meant to just be print. Any suggestions or guides on making code more user friendly would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`1895..1913 === 1895` is the same as `1895..(1913 === 1895)`, and what you want is `(1895..1913) === 1895`.

See [Ruby Operator Precedence](https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby%20operator%20precedence).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be the parenthesis.
Ruby isn't able to properly guess how it should evaluate the line.

The following works for example :

```
(1895..1913) === 1895
```